# Paracompact but not Lindelöf and vice versa

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, paracompactness, lindelof-spaces

We know that a regular Lindelöf space is paracompact. Can anybody give me an example where the space is Lindelöf but not paracompact ?

I have found that $\mathbb{R}$ with discrete topology is paracompact but not Lindelöf. Are there other examples of this type i.e., paracompact but not Lindelöf ?

Comment: I see. That's why my example worked. Thank you.

Comment: [Here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/when-is-a-lindelof-space-normal/) is an example of a Lindelöf space which is Hausdorff but not normal, and hence not paracompact.